# Ansible: How to execute multiple commands with `ansible -a`

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

This works:

```
  ansible host -a "echo hello"                # hello
```

But this returned a weird answer

```
  ansible host -a "echo hello && echo world"      # hello && echo world
```

Does ansible escape `&&` and `;` with `ansible -a`?

How can I excute it?

Answer (score 5):

By default `ansible` CLI uses `command` module, which does not feed its arguments trough shell.

You want to use `shell` module instead:

```
ansible host -m shell -a 'echo hello && echo world'
```

Answer (score 3):

I remembered that ansible uses just ssh.

```
# not work
ansible host -a "echo hello && echo world"
# works
ansible host -a "bash -c 'echo hello && echo world'"
```

The command is excuted just through the ssh command.